# WebCam Multichannel Microphone

Tags: microphone

I have a webcam multichannel with microphone, but only the camera appears: the microphone doesn't work, i tried install a lot of audio applications, but no success (i.e. `pulseaudio`, `guvscviewl`, `cheese`).

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 258a:002a SINO WEALTH Gaming KB 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:08a0 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1224:2a25 Jieli Technology USB PHY 2.0<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

USB PHY 2.0 mono
```

I did some research but I was not able to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Fedora 32 here, Kernel 5.8.13-200.fc32.x86_64. For me it appears even without a name in lsusb. It somehow works, in the sense that it is recognized by the system. But it sounds awful, something like 8bit 4kHz - Robot voice, zero intelligibility

Comment: Related: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/68141 but I'm far off compiling my own kernel

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3 XFCE on a Lenovo X140e. Camera works great in Zoom and Cheese, but mic doesn't. It shows up in pavucontrol, but no sound indication when I tap on the webcam.